# How to make a dynamic textbox in visual basic 2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I am new to vb 2008,i am trying to make an application to calculate molarity(chemistry).

Below is the equation (for non chemistry)

```
              M1V1=M2V2
```

where M1 and M2 are Molarity and V1,V2 are volume(all variables).

so for my application i have made four textbox and a button.Now what i have done is my application only can find one variable M2 when provided other three values

eg

```
              M2=(M1V1)/V2
```

i want to know how i can make this application more dynamic

lets say
i want to find

```
   M1,M2,V1 or V2 any of these,just providing the other three values
```

I think it can be done using if else statment but i dont know how to do it

Advance thanks for your help

Comment: ...and try voting on some of the help you're getting.

Comment: dear friends,sorry but i dont know how to accept answers,i tried to vote for replied answers but stackover didnt allowed me(it says my score is less than 15),any way thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

I would handle this in this manner.

I would name my four textboxes:

```
txtM1
txtM2
txtV1
txtV2
```

then

Create:

```
 Private Sub textbox_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtM1.TextChanged, txtM2.TextChanged, txtV1.TextChanged, txtV2.TextChanged
               Select Case True
        Case txtM1.Text <> "" AndAlso _
             txtV1.Text <> "" AndAlso _
             txtV2.Text <> ""
            txtM2.Text = CInt((txtM1.Text * txtV1.Text) / txtV2.Text)
        Case txtM2.Text <> "" AndAlso _
             txtV1.Text <> "" AndAlso _
             txtV2.Text <> ""
            txtM1.Text = "Your formula for M1"
        Case txtM1.Text <> "" AndAlso _
             txtM2.Text <> "" AndAlso _
             txtV1.Text <> ""
            txtV2.Text = "Your formula for V2"
        Case txtM1.Text <> "" AndAlso _
             txtM2.Text <> "" AndAlso _
             txtV2.Text <> ""
            txtV1.Text = "Your formula for V1"
    End Select        End Sub
```